# Add line break between imagen and text with VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I have the following script to add signature in Outlook:

```
...
Set objShape = objSelection.InlineShapes.AddPicture("\\blabla\blabla\blabla\blabla\blabla\" & strlogin2 & ".jpg") 

url = "http://url.com.mx/assets/aviso.pdf"
objSelection.Font.Italic = True
objSelection.Font.Size = 09
objSelection.TypeText "El Aviso de Privacidad de XXXXXX, está disponible en "
Set objLink = objSelection.Hyperlinks.Add(objSelection.Range, url)
objSelection.TypeText ", es aplicable a todos los Titulares de Datos Personales obtenidos por la Empresa, a través de cualquier medio físico o electrónico y para los fines que se hace referencia en el mismo."
objSelection.Font.Color = RGB(255, 102, 0)
objLink.Range.Font.Name = "Calibri" 
objLink.Range.Font.Size = 09 
objLink.Range.Font.Bold = True 
objSelection.Font.Bold = True
objSelection.Font.Color = RGB(105, 105, 105)
objSelection.Font.Color = RGB(105, 105, 105)

objSelection.TypeParagraph()

Set objSelection = objDoc.Range()
objSignatureEntries.Add "Firma Corporativa XXXX", objSelection
objSignatureObject.NewMessageSignature = "Firma Corporativa XXXXXX"
objSignatureObject.ReplyMessageSignature = "Firma Corporativa XXXXX"
objDoc.Saved = True
objWord.Quit
```

This is the result:

[image]

I need set a line break between the image and text.

Comment: Can you just add `VbCrLf` after the image and before the text?

Comment: thank you but it not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type a paragraph after you inserted the image:

```
Set objShape = objSelection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(...)
objSelection.TypeParagraph
```

Comment: still the same issue :(

Comment: I doubt that. Please provide evidence.